# Is it possible to disable the mobile UI features in tinyMCE 5

Tags: mobile, tinymce

Is it possible to disable the mobile UI feature in tinyMCE, and just show the regular editor?
I'm asking because it only shows a blank screen for me, in mobile (when I click on the "book" icon in the editor box.
I've searched for solutions to the blank page and I only found vague references to "a parent element having overflow set to anything but visible" which didn't help me much.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT November 2019: TinyMCE 5.1 switches to the Silver theme by default on mobile devices. This workaround is no longer necessary.

---

Our documentation doesn't explicitly explain how to do this, and it isn't something we test so you may run into unexpected issues, but it is certainly possible.

Our mobile UI is implemented as a theme, even in TinyMCE 5, similar to how `modern` was our desktop theme for version 4 and `silver` is for version 5. By default when the editor detects it is on a mobile device the theme is set to `mobile` - we removed this from the v5 docs, but [our v4 docs describe the defaults](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/mobile/):

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  mobile: {
    theme: 'mobile'
  }
});
```

By extension of this concept, where the mobile block overrides the config, you can specify the mobile theme to be `modern` in TinyMCE 4, `silver` in TinyMCE 5 and the desktop interface will show:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  mobile: {
    theme: 'silver'
  }
});
```

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate this which loads the desktop theme on my phone.
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/C9gaab/1

Comment: This is still a bit of a trainwreck. I wanted to disable the mobile experience entirely because the mobile theme won't allow me to do certain tool items, or do them in a way I don't want. For example, the link dialog won't appear, and in the mobile theme it allows title and other attributes, which I don't want. The image picker won't even let me stay with URL's, allowing to pick something to upload.

Comment: Yeah, the mobile theme is quite restrictive at the moment. But desktop editing doesn't have any of the mobile behaviour optimisations. We're scheduling another pass at the mobile theme in the coming months.

Comment: Update: We are working on mobile compatibility in the silver theme - some of these changes are already showing up in the latest release if you use my patch above. Once that's ready (we are targeting version 5.1) we will delete the mobile theme and redirect all platforms to silver.

Comment: @Spyder till the new version is out I would like to remove the mobile detection. Would it be (good) working if I edit the source code and return false for each DeviceType (line 3420 in tinymce.js current version).

Comment: @HannesOberreiter you won't need to shortly. We're working on a fix for the mobile plugin filter such that it depends on the theme rather than the device. At that point the theme override should be all you need. Adjusting the device type code may have unforeseen consequences in other areas.

Comment: TinyMCE 5.1 is now available, and the silver theme is enabled by default on mobile devices.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to enable plugins (image, media, fullscreen etc.):

in config:

```
...
mobile: {
    theme: 'silver'
},
...
```

in tinymce.min.js:

find

```
"lists","autolink","autosave"
```

replace to

```
"advlist", "autolink", "lists", "link", "image", "anchor", "searchreplace", "code", "fullscreen", "media", "table", "paste", "codesample"
```

or any plugins you need

I know, that source files should not be edited, but only this method helped me.

Comment: You could also change that in the source files and compile TinyMCE yourself. But we only test mobile with the whitelist of plugins so we make no guarantees about whether other plugins work on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

config the mobile like this:

```
mobile: {
  theme: "silver",
  menubar: false,
  height: 300,
  max_height: 500,
  max_width: 500,
  min_height: 400,
  statusbar: false,
  toolbar: false,
  plugins: ["autosave", "lists", "autolink"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just lost a night of sleep over this, so here's the dirty fix while @spyder can figure it out:

First, download the dev (unminified) version of tinyMCE [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/self-hosted/)

Then, edit the file tinymce.js - Modify the function isOnMobile (should be around line 11930) to always return false, like this:

```
var isOnMobile = function (isTouchDevice, sectionResult) {
    var isInline = sectionResult.settings().inline;
    return false; //isTouchDevice && !isInline;
};
```

Finally, Save your changes and minify again (the unminified file is 1mb!). There are several online tools that can do this for you in case you don't these tools in place already.

Note that this only works if you are self-hosting. It ain't pretty, but until there is an official fix, it WORKS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this from the viewpoint of TinyMCE 6 but I think the same logic would work with TinyMCE 5 if you still want to use it for some reason.

The automatic switch to mobile features is poorly documented, but the logic seems to be that TinyMCE init object can include the property `mobile` to set defaults for the mobile clients. However, if you don't define this property, the TinyMCE internal default will be used instead of your generic config in the init object! This obviously results mobile clients getting totally different UI from the other clients.

As a result, you should *always* define the `mobile` property of your TinyMCE init object and use settings you've tested to work with the tools you use. For example, you could use configuration like

```
mobile: { // undo default mobile settings applied by TinyMCE core – many of these are not officially supported but seem to work pretty well with modern Android and iOS
    resize: true,
    object_resizing: "img",
    menubar: true,
    toolbar_mode: "floating",
    toolbar_sticky: true,
    table_grid: true,
}
```

or something similar to that. To see the currently available documentation, see https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/tinymce-for-mobile/#configuring-mobile