# how to remove the gray overlay in Android using tinymce

Tags: android, tinymce, textarea

I use tinymce for a `textarea`. My code looks like this

```
<textarea id="tinymce" class="tinymce form-control custom-control" name="message" placeholder="BERICHT"></textarea>
```

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector : ".tinymce",
    plugins: "emoticons maxchars placeholder link",

    menubar: false,
    toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline | fontsizeselect | link | emoticons',

    selector : "textarea",
    height: 300,
    force_br_newlines : true,
    force_p_newlines : false,
    forced_root_block : '',
    mobile: {
        theme: 'mobile',
        plugins: 'emoticons maxchars placeholder link',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline | fontsizeselect | link | emoticons'
    }                   
});
```

On mobile devices, i see a gray overlay on the textarea like image below:
[image]

How can i remove this gray overlay so that it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this: [Is it possible to disable the mobile UI features in tinyMCE 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54579110/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-mobile-ui-features-in-tinymce-5#)
you should use a different theme (silver) for mobile devices:

```
mobile: {
    theme: 'silver'
  }
```